# Can't render camera preview on iOS with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I trying to make a Native module to React Native using native camera api from objective C, but I can't render camera, I only can render the background set in layoutSubviews method.

My RNCameraManager.m file:

```objectivec
#import "RNCameraManager.h"
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
#import "RNCamera.h"

@interface RNCameraManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RNCameraManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(RNCameraManager)

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[RNCamera alloc] initWithBridge:self.bridge];
}

@end
```

My RNCamera.m file:

```objectivec
#import "RNCamera.h"
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>

@interface RNCamera ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;

@end

@implementation RNCamera

- (id)initWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  if((self = [super init])) {
    self.bridge = bridge;
    self.session = [AVCaptureSession new];
    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  }
  
  return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  self.previewLayer.frame = self.bounds;
  [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [self.layer insertSublayer:self.previewLayer atIndex:0];
}

@end
```

When I call this method in React Native, I only get a Red Screen (beacause I set red to background color).

I set view size on react native render, (When I try to switch RN Camera to Maps, works perfectly, so the problem is time to actually render the camera and not the view)

[My render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C7bC.jpg)

**edit 1 (react native code):**

RNCamera.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  requireNativeComponent,
  Platform,
  PermissionsAndroid,
} from 'react-native';

const RNCamera = requireNativeComponent('RNCamera');

export default RNCamera;
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

import RNCamera from './RNCamera';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera style={styles.camera} />
        <Text>Hello RN</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  camera: {
    width: 220,
    height: 220,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: How do you create the preview layer? Show that as well.

Comment: I updated de answer with my react native code but it is probably not the problem.

If you are refering preview layer in objective-c, I don't have more code besides the ones I put here (and maybe it is the problem to render camera).

You can check code repo here https://github.com/akinncar/CameraApp/tree/main/ios